# Tensors notation

Tags: tensors

Below is a relation in tensor representation
$$ K_{}^{\mu}=C^{\mu}+\frac{1}{2}M_{k}^{\mu}\partial_{\nu}M_{k}^{\nu}  $$

Is there a way to represent it as tensors or matrices? I am not sure how to represent the differential operators in tensor form?

Comment: It already equates two rank-$1$ tensors.

Comment: The index balance is incorrect: $k$ appears twice below.

Comment: @IvoTerek Actually, I wouldn't worry about that. Note it's a Roman index, not a Greek one. It's customary to keep internal symmetries' indices downstairs because the contracting metric is the Kronecker delta.